# problem using apt-get: error 13 access denied

Tags: apt, updates

When I run `apt-get update` I get the following error message:

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/lock unable- open (13: access denied)
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale You might benefit from that one. What exactly is the issue that you are having troubles with?

Comment: @Emrah: You should run `sudo apt-get update`. Check ByteCommander's answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you ran apt-get as your normal user, but it requires root privileges. Therefore, you must type `sudo apt-get update` which will ask you for your own password (don't worry about no characters getting displayed, this is normal. just hit enter when finished). After that it should run without any errors.

If this post helped you, please accept the answer by clicking the green tick next to it. Thank you!